# Cannot perform create operation on resource on rails 5 active admin on heroku. Gets internal server error

Tags: heroku, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5

Im creating a rails api with an activeadmin dashboard on heroku.The api works with seeded data but i cant make any entries using the activeadmin interface. It returns a 500 error the moment the form is submitted. Im sure its pretty minor but i cant figure out what the problem is. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: i found the problem. the logs didn't show this till now.. a merge of rep branches changed the permitted params for the resource. So i was getting a forbidden attribute error.